# How to get rid of <reference path="

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015, resharper, typescript1.8

Sorry everyone, I've been struggling trying to understand why I need the

```
/// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />

module App {
    angular.module("app", [""]);
}
```

I'm using `typings` and here is my `tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "files": [

  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

I found already several posts about, but every time a different answer and a different scenario.

I use `Visual Studio 2015` with `ReSharper`, `TypeScript 1.8.5`

Once I remove `<reference...` tag `ReSharper` says *"Cannot find name 'angular'"* but the application runs normally. (probably because it cannot find the intellisense anymore)

Has anyone faced the same problem? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs on `tsconfig`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json#details):

> If no "files" property is present in a tsconfig.json, the compiler
>   defaults to including all TypeScript (*.ts or *.tsx) files in the
>   containing directory and subdirectories. When a "files" property is
>   present, only the specified files are included.

You are using an empty files array (`"files": []`) which means no files are going to be included in the compiler context. Either add all your references to the `files` array, or remove the `files` property completely to allow the compiler to include *all* TS files in context.

Alternatively, you can use `import` and `export` module syntax instead.

Comment: thanks, but if I remove `files` property, I get thousand of errors when building my application. If I add for example: `files: ["typings/browser.d.ts"]` I still get the same warning that "Cannot find name 'angular'"

Comment: What "thousand of errors" do you get? Is your `typings` directory in the same directory as your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Yes, same directory: here is a bit more clarified: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36080113/typescript-error-cannot-find-name-in-visual-studio

Comment: Once I removed "files". I had to put "typings" as part of excluded folders and now Visual Studio stopped complaining. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use one _reference.ts file with all referenced *.d.ts lybraries which I use. The typescript compiler use it information for import defenitions about js lybraries. The second case there reference are used is managing the order of ts files include into resulting js file. Another words if you add reference in file B.ts to A.ts in  resulting js will be contains A.js first and B after. It's not often needed because TSC is smart and ordered file by types using but some times It's usefull then you use some suff from A.ts in B.ts dynamicly (not stronrly typed).

Comment: the meaning of `tsconfig` file is to avoid references so using a _reference.ts does not make sense and does not solve my issue.

Comment: I use _reference only for error check in VS. For building I use gulp with simple task: var destPath = "/Scripts",
            soucesFiles = ["/../**/*.ts", "../Lib/*.d.ts"];
        tsResult = gulp.src(soucesFiles)
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts({
        declaration: true,
        target: "ES5",
        noImplicitAny: false,
        out: "app.js"
    }))