# TypeScript error: "Cannot find name" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, tsconfig

I've seen a lot of threads and discussions about that but I'm not getting to fix the issue. [This is my post from some days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037962/how-to-get-rid-of-reference-path/36040269?noredirect=1#comment59753460_36040269).

One of the purposes of `typings` is to avoid the use of `<reference>` tags, right?

But if I don't use it, Visual Studio complains:

[image]

Visual Studio stops complaining once I reference `browser.d.ts`.

Here is my `tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "files": [

  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

I also tried removing the `"files"` property from the `tsconfig` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037962/how-to-get-rid-of-reference-path/36040269?noredirect=1#comment59753460_36040269), but if I do this, I get compilation error in other typescript files inside the ambient folder of typings.

The code runs and all is fine, but I want to understand if I'm doing something wrong or if it's a Visual Studio problem.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might have the same issue in the future:

I fixed the issue. The secret is to exclude the `"files"` property from `tsconfig` and in the `"excluded"` section add the folder `"typings"`.

The `tsconfig` should now look like that:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "typings",
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed adding `"jasmine"` into `"types"` section in `tsconfig.json`. Like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "noEmitOnError": true,
      "removeComments": false,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es5"
    },
    "exclude": [
      "typings",
      "node_modules",
      "wwwroot"
    ],
    "types": ["jasmine"]
}
```